# Switch Variables Depending on If Statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I'm trying to create a program where it switches the variables depending on, in this case, as an example, what animal you've chosen. Without having to use the print command twice.

For example. I created two strings:

```
String thingsForDogs = "bone";
String thingsForCats = "yarn";
```

And those strings would switch with each other, when printing out the result, depending on what the user chose as an animal. I don't know how I would code this, but if the user chose Cat as their animal, they would get a different output than if they've chosen Dog.

I know I could do something like this:

```
System.out.println("What animal do you want to be? Dog or cat?");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
char choice = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);

if(choice == 'c' || choice == 'C')
        System.out.println("You have " + thingsForCats);
else if(choice == 'd' || choice == 'D')
        System.out.println("You have " + thingsForDogs);
```

But I still don't know how I could do it, without having to repeat the print command. I'm trying to print it all in one print command, but the variable along with it being printed, is switched, depending on what the user chose as their animal.

Comment: FYI - There are some mistakes in your code. nextLine should be nextLine(). You have thingsForCats listed twice in the IF-ELSE statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is exactly. The code you've posted would work (except `kb.nextLine` should be `kb.nextLine()`).

Comment: Sorry about that, should have made that more clear, I fixed that mistake with the `nextLine()`. I meant along the lines of not having to repeat the print command. All in one print command.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

You may change it wo a swich:

```
System.out.print("You have ");
switch(choice){

    case "c":
    case "C":
        System.out.println(thingsForCats);
        break;
    case "d":
    case "D":
        System.out.println(thingsForDogs);
        break;
    default:
        // some errorhandling or Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `HashMap` to store that data and avoid the if-statement all together.

```
HashMap<char, String> map = new HashMap();
map.add('c', "yarn");
map.add('d', "bone");
...
// convert the input to lower case so you don't have to check both lower
// and upper cases
char choice = Character.toLowerCase(kb.nextLine().charAt(0));
System.out.println("You have " + map.get(choice));
```

Comment: I'll try that. I'm just new to Java, so I haven't learned anything like HashMaps, but I am aware of changing to lowercase, I forgot how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

There you have, one line printing

```
String thingsForPet = "";
System.out.println("What animal do you want to be? Dog or cat?");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
char choice = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);

thingsForPet = Character.toLowerCase(choice) == 'c' ? "yarn" : "bone";
System.out.println("You have " + thingsForPet);
```

Considering your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067702/switch-variables-depending-on-if-statement/24068146#comment37113786_24067920) you can change last 2 lines as:

```
if(choice == 'c' || choice == 'C') {
    thingsForPet = "yarn";
}
else {
    thingsForPet = "bone";
}
System.out.println("You have " + thingsForPet);
```